# How to accept two different status codes in a MockMvc test?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, mockmvc

I need to test an HTTP endpoint in an integration test. There are two acceptable responses:

- **Status code 200**, in which case I need to check if content is JSON and look for a particular element value in the body, or
- **Status code is 5xx**, in which case I do nothing. (The goal is for my test not to fail when the service I'm calling is not responding.)

I know how to test each acceptable response separately. Example (Kotlin):

```
    mockMvc.get("/myresource") {
        contentType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON
        accept = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON
    }.andExpect {
        status { isOk() }
        content { contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) }
        jsonPath("$.greeting", `is`("Hello SO"))
    }
```

and:

```
    mockMvc.get("/myresource") {
        contentType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON
        accept = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON
    }.andExpect {
        status { is5xxServerError() }
    }
```

How can I combine both acceptable responses in a single test?

I hope I don't need to resort to `RestTemplate`.

Comment: I asked ChatGpt the same question. It suggested `mockMvc.perform(get("/my-endpoint")).andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful().or().isNotFound())`  but I can't seem to find the import for `or()`  that could make this work. I'm using Spring boot 2.7.2.

Answer (score 3):

It's not as simple as accepting two status codes: depending on the actual status, further assertions may be needed regarding the content and json path. So this scenario is more complex than it may seem, and I doubt built-in `ResultMatchers` support it. The fact that the scenario also tests two *completely different* outcomes does not help the case for adding such support in the spring-test project.

That being said, there are ways to build the expectations to conditionally perform the assertions:

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/myresource"))
       .andExpect(status().is(anyOf(is(HttpStatus.OK), new CustomMatcher<>("status should be 5xx") {
           @Override
           public boolean matches(Object status) {
               return status instanceof Integer
                 && HttpStatus.Series.SERVER_ERROR.equals(HttpStatus.valueOf((int) status).series());
                }
            })))
       .andExpect(mvcResult -> {
                if (mvcResult.getResponse().getStatus() == HttpStatus.OK.value()) {
                    content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).match(mvcResult);
                    jsonPath("$.greeting", is("Hello SO")).match(mvcResult);
                }
       })
```

This translates to:

- I expect the status to be either 200 or a 5xx error,
- and I expect that if the status is ok, then the content matches my expected value

Answer (score 2):

Java:

```java
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.anyOf;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.oneOf;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.allOf;

mockMvc.stuff().andExpect(status().is(oneOf(200, 503)))

mockMvc.stuff()
       .andExpect(status().is(anyOf(allOf(lessThan(505), greaterThan(500)),
                                    allOf(lessThan(205), greaterThan(200)))));
```

The `is()` after `status()` is [this one](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/result/StatusResultMatchers.html#is(org.hamcrest.Matcher)). What I wrote isn't necessarily the best way to do it with Hamcrest matchers (which there are a *lot* of to choose from). Also, you may be best served by writing your own. But that's the general idea.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answers by MA and neofelis (thanks much!), I was able to find a solution (in Kotlin).

### Requirements

- If the status code is any 5xx, then the test shall pass (be ignored).
- If not 5xx, shall test for a specific 2xx or 4xx success code (some tests expect 200, others 201, 202, 404, 422, etc.). In this case, shall also test elements of the response (body, headers).
- The 5xx verification shall be reusable across several tests and test units.

### Solution

Reusable `CustomMatcher` to identify a 5xx status code:

```
fun isServerError5xx() = IsServerError5xx()

class IsServerError5xx : CustomMatcher<Any?>("Check if status code is 5xx") {
    override fun matches(status: Any?): Boolean =
        if (status == null || status !is Int)
            false
        else
            HttpStatus.resolve(status)?.is5xxServerError == true
}
```

Example of `MockMvc` test (using the MockMvc DSL):

```
mockMvc.get("/myresource") {
    contentType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON
    accept = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON
}.andExpect {
    status { `is`(anyOf(`is`(HttpStatus.OK.value()), isServerError5xx())) }
    match {
        if (it.response.status == HttpStatus.OK.value()) {
            content { contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) }
            jsonPath("$.greeting", `is`("Hello SO"))
        }
    }
}
```

Same example **not** using the MockMvc DSL:

```
mockMvc.perform(
    get(""/myresource"")
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
)
    .andExpect(status().`is`(anyOf(`is`(HttpStatus.OK.value()), isServerError5xx())))
    .andExpect { mvcResult: MvcResult ->
        if (mvcResult.response.status == HttpStatus.OK.value()) {
            content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).match(mvcResult)
            jsonPath("$.greeting", `is`("Hello SO"))
        }
    }
```